# using co-ordinates from a Features Collection to find centroid co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, geojson, turfjs

Apologies, I'm new to javascript!

I have 8 Features Collections in my script, which make 8 polygon layers on my webmap, representing species distribution for 8 different frog species. Each corresponds to a button (an img of each frog) on the page, and onclick loads the polygon, triggers a pop up in the centre and changes the setView to the centre. For this I need the polygon centroid.

Each of the 8 Features Collections has co-ordinates of the polygon corner points. I want to use these co-ordinates in a turf transformation to find the centroid (centre point) of each polygon. I need the centroids so I can set the centre of the map so when the map pans onto a polygon layer it centres on the polygon centre, and a popup marker appears at this centre.

I *could* enter the co-ordinates manually from each layer's Features Collection into the turf.centroid(polygon) feature, but each polygon has a LOT of points and there is 8 polygons. I'd also then have to copy the result of the operation into L.LatLng and L.Marker too.

I need a way to get the corner co-ordinates from the features collection into the turf operation, and then putting the resultant centroid co-ordinates into the L.LatLng and L.Marker features. Any ideas?

Here is the code for a function called addFrog1Layer() in which I add a polygon layer & a pop-up to the map:

```
var polygon = turf.polygon([[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f], [g, h], [i, j], [k, l]]]);

var centroid = turf.centroid(polygon);

map.setView(new L.LatLng(x,y), 1);

Frog1Layer = L.geoJson(Frog1, { 
        style: {
            weight: 0.5,
            color: 'white',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: 'red',
        }

}).addTo(map);


var frogIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'frogIcon.png',

iconSize:     [30, 30],
iconAnchor:   [30, 30], 
popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]

L.marker([x,y], {icon: frogIcon}).bindPopup("I am a pop-up").addTo(map);
```

Comment: Any comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed code that could be your solution. The code demonstrates how to get coordinates x and y that you need.

```js
console.log("Hello World of Turf! ");

var polygon = turf.polygon([[[-5, 52], [-4, 56], [-2, 51], [-7, 54], [-5, 52]]], { name: 'poly1' });
var centroid = turf.centroid(polygon);

// get coordinates of the centroid
var centroid_xy = centroid.geometry.coordinates;

// get x and y
var x = centroid_xy[0];
var y = centroid_xy[1];
console.log("Centroid x: " + x);
console.log("Centroid y: " + y);
  
console.log("Goodbye Turf! ");
```

```html
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
```